# GWT - Development Mode с помощью Apache Tomcat

Tags: ant, gwt, java, tomcat

Как это возможно сделать? Скрипт для запуска dev mode через ANt такой:

```
<target name="run.devmode" depends="компиляция и т.д.">
        <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="src"/>
                <path refid="common_library"/>
                <pathelement location="web/WEB-INF/classes"/>
            </classpath>
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx512M"/>
            <arg value="-startupUrl"/>
            <arg value="${gwt.startup.url}"/>
            <arg value="-war"/>
            <arg value="${gwt.war}"/>
            <arg value="${gwt.module.name}"/>
        </java>
    </target>
```

Так вот запускается встроенный Jetty, а он не понимает jstl теги в jsp и другую лабуду.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, вы всегда можете запускать сервер отдельно, а hosted mode отдельно указав -noserver.

Во-вторых, Если Jetty многое не понимает, то вы можете скомпилировать с помощью jasper, а библиотеку с JSTL притащить на борту проекта (собственно, tomcat тоже сам не имеет реализации JSTL).

**UPD**

Запускаем tomcat наподобие этого (выдрал из своего build.xml):

```
        <java fork="true" classpathref="trader.classpath" classname="org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap">
            <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=${home}"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Dspring.config=${home}/etc/****.env.xml"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Dxml.config.file=${home}/tmp/***.xml"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Dconfig.file=${home}/tmp/util.cfg"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Dejbclient.backend_connector.ior_url=http://${core.server}.****.com:8080/ns0.ior"/>
            <jvmarg line="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=11056,server=y,suspend=n" />
                    <!-- ещё всякий шлак для CORBA и EJB -->
        </java>
```

Отдельно запускаем hosted mode

```
    <target name="run.devmode" depends="компиляция и т.д.">
        <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode">
            <!-- тут ваши обычные параметры -->
            <arg value="-noserver" />
        </java>
    </target>
```

Comment: А если проект на спринг? Что значит запускать сервер отдельно? Что делает -noserver атрибут?

Comment: -noserver заставляет hosted mode консоль не запускать Jetty, а только слушать браузерные подключения. А томкат просто запустите обычным способом и задеплойте приложение в него. Я всё время работаю в таком режиме.

Comment: Будьте добры, по шагам, как это сделать :)

Comment: Имеется: 1. папка web 2. src-модуль gwt 3-томкат, который смотрит в папку web

Comment: Ну вот.. у вас есть всё необходимое.

Comment: а что потом? Обращаюсь, скажем, к index.jsp -> там ссылка на скомпиленный js, или открывать index.html, который по умолчанию?

Comment: Единственный минус в том, что вам придётся запускать GWT-компиляцию отдельно, чтобы результат можно было залить в томкат.

Comment: Да и где гвт создаёт временную папку с модулем в твоём случае? У меня в папке web создаётся постоянно mypack.mypack2.ModuleName, который нужно удалять(

Comment: У меня (у нас) все это делается в отдельной build-папке, которая превращается в exploded war. Потом всё это копируется в директорию, на которую смотрит томкат.

Comment: Вот интересно, а как вы в ие6 тестируете приложение на гвт? Неужели только в готовом виде?

Comment: А при чём тут IE6? Отладка как работала так и работает.. разница-то какая?

Comment: Однако, вы правы: в IE6 обычно ломается только вёрстка, а для неё отладка и не нужна, так что тестируем только в готовом виде. Вообще, вёрстка готовится отдельной командой, так что мы просто применяем её и вообще только в одном своём браузере пробуем и всё. Если что не так, QA выкатит баг и будем смотреть.

Comment: Понятно. Т.е. всё выглядит так: 1) пишем код gwt 2) для запуска этого модуля, выполняем ант-скрипт devmode, который запускает страницу html (или index.jsp) (т.к. ссылка ведёт не на готовый js а на js с байт-кодом) 3) есс-но копируем весь "war" в отдельную папку 4) в ней же гвт создаёт временные папки - имя модуля (ссылка js в html) 5) запускаем страницу в фф + gwt plugin, в котором gwt=ссылка на js + байткод. и вуаля, работают все внешние библиотеки, dwr, spring, flash и т.д. Я всё правильно написал?

Comment: Да, выглядит верно

Comment: Попробую. Спасибо. Я всё время запускал Jetty :)